# Insert filename into directory link from cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a list of 150 filenames in column A e.g. WorkBook1-WorkBook150 and want to reference this when including the file directory so I will be able to reference a cell out of the workbook. The cell is an outstanding amount for a particular supplier so I wish to create a workbook to have a full overview of the outstanding amount and broken down for each supplier in a list.

A1 filename: File1.xls

So if filename 1 is in A1, is there a way to action this so we can pull the filename from A1 and insert it in the relevant place in the directory? It works if I input the text from A1 manually but referencing the cell into the relevant place would save a lot of time.

Example of what I wish to input in B1: ='C:\Directory\FolderName[A1]Sheet1'!$D$4

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow! Would you be able to add a screenshot? It could make it easier to imagine the kind of problem you are trying to solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need is the 'CONCATENATE' formula. A1 contains 'filename.xls'. In B1 you can put: 'C:\Directory\FolderName\'
In C1 you can then put

```
=CONCATENATE(B1;A1)
```

which gives you

C:\Directory\FolderName\filename.xls

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this. This will only show the filename and potentially could be useful but i'm not sure how to incorporate this to get the full working formula above from this. E.g. ='C:\Directory\FolderName[A1]Sheet1'!$D$4.

Comment: you want to parse the formula that is inside A1?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make it where you choose from a list you would need to use the data validation button and make a list. Make sure you have the reference in another cell.

Then you can use concatenate with the drop-down cell for efficiency.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this. 

The A column will display the company names in the filename. The B column will display the outstanding amount for that particular supplier, pulling the amount from each individual supplier statement's excel sheet.

The external files are statements with debt outstanding and I will be pulling the cell showing the outstanding debt and displaying these in an overview list to keep track of the total debt outstanding for all suppliers.

Comment: If you could include a screenshot of what you are looking at that would be helpful. I believe I understand what you are trying to do but I cannot be sure.